# Images will load from ".html", but are not loading at run-time from the ".js" file when deployed to server

Tags: javascript, html, image, localhost, netlify

Please help me out. I have wasted all of the day trying to solve this problem. I couldn't, thats why I am asking for help here.

My images are loaded on run-time through javascript from "index.js" file. The images are shown when on localhost but when i build the project for the production, then the images that supposed to be load at run-time using the "index.js" file, will not be showing BUT if i put the same image in the ".html" file, it will load.

There are same queries in the past like this, and the answer to those queries here is that:
1- Github is case-sensitive so use all small letters
2- put ./ at the start or remove / from the url.

My problem is nothing like the above. It is something else. Here is the link to my github: https://github.com/Yasirkhan6499/tweet-personal

Please I need your help!!!

Comment: In the `production` build, can you check the `<img src` of the problematic images by inspecting them?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: yes, i have inspected them, the "src" is fine. its just does not show up on the production while on localhost the images will be shown. its a weird one.